# sailsjs: model email validation seems not to work

Tags: validation, email, model, sails.js

On a fresh sailsjs installation, I've got a test model defined like this:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    username:{
      type:'string'
    }
    ,email:{
      type:'string'
      ,email:true
    }
  }
};
```

And if I navigate to this:

```
http://localhost:1337/user/create?username=stratboy1&email=test@wow.com
```

I get this error:

```
{
  "error": "E_VALIDATION",
  "status": 400,
  "summary": "1 attribute is invalid",
  "model": "User",
  "invalidAttributes": {
    "email": [
      {
        "rule": "email",
        "message": "\"email\" validation rule failed for input: 'test@wow.com'"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any of you knows why?

Comment: Have you tried url-encoding the `@`? `@ => %40`

Comment: Mmm it doesn't work. Very same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come across this earlier but don't quite remember the cause.

As a quick fix, you can substitute

```
email: { type: 'string', email: true }
```

with

```
email: { type: 'email' }
```

Comment: interesting, but that type is not officially documented: maybe it will default to something else?

Comment: it works, you're right, and will even correctly run email validation. Still, it's not documented, so I'm wandering if it will be deprecated, or the opposite, maybe it's the new way and docs are outdated.. weird..

Comment: Alright, I just tried both syntaxes and they worked fine. What Waterline and Sails versions are you using? I'm using Sails 0.11.0 and Waterline 0.10.23.

Comment: sails 0.11.2. I don't know how to tell waterline's version. I guess the newest one though, since it's  a fresh sails app installation.

Comment: That is weird since I had earlier come across this bug on an older version, which means it was probably fixed. I'm too occupied to dig into this at the moment, do comment if you find the cause though.

Comment: I found the [documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/concepts/ORM/Validations.md) for this after scratching my head for a while! Essentially, `email` is a typealias for `string` that gets run through a validation rule built into sails.